# Angularjs $http POST request empty array

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

The following `$http request` executes successfully, yet the PHP script on the other end receives an empty `$_POST` array when it should receive 'test' and 'testval.' Any ideas?

```
$http({
    url: 'backend.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {'test': 'testval'},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you wan to send just that simple data, try this:

```
$http({
    url: 'backend.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: 'test=' + testval,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
```

And php part shoul be like this:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['test'];
    $echo $data;
?>
```

It is working for me.

Comment: I was hoping you could take a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480438/how-to-grab-php-data-from-angularjs

?

The problem I'm encountering is similar but has some distinct differences from the one posted in this thread.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the examples at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http under `Shortcut methods`:
`$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`
`$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

The top answer on this question explains it well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: Hi All, in my condition changing only the headers was not enough to send the data . I also overrided transformRequest method like  as pointed in the link http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/19254029.html then now I successfully send the data to backend .

Answer (score 7):

This is a common issue with AngularJS.

The first step is to change the default *content-type* header for **POST** request:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;";
```

Then, using an **XHR request interceptor**, it is necessary to serialize properly the payload object:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            if (config.data && typeof config.data === 'object') {
                // Check https://gist.github.com/brunoscopelliti/7492579 
                // for a possible way to implement the serialize function.
                config.data = serialize(config.data);
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
}]);
```

In this way, payload data will be again available in the **$_POST** array.

For more info about [XHR interceptor](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/xhr-interceptor-in-an-angularjs-web-app).

Another possibility, it is to mantain the default *content-type* header, and then server side parse the payload:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"], "application/json") === 0) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

More simplified way:

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {        
        if (data === undefined) { return data; } 
        return $.param(data);
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'; 
});
```

Comment: You should be cursing PHP

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following line, and the preceding comma:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

And then the data will appear in $_POST. You only need that line if you are uploading a file, in which case you'll have to decode the body to get the data vars.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I removed the line but didn't have any luck. The print_r($_POST) command in my PHP script is still returning an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution here http://www.peterbe.com/plog/what-stumped-me-about-angularjs. There is a piece of code in the "AJAX doesn't work like jQuery" section, which solved my problem.