# How to grab php data from angularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

I've been able to sent FormData from angularJS to php, but I don't know how to do the reverse. I'm currently trying to get the $base64 variable into my angularJS, but I'm quite stumped on how to go about doing so. The documentation in the official angularJS doesn't help me much either

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

JS

```
$scope.MakeGray_Button = function(){
    if ($scope.imageUrl) {
        var MakeGray_Form = new FormData();
        MakeGray_Form.append("FileName", $scope.imageUrl);
        $http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.php",
        data   : MakeGray_Form,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).
        success(function(){                     
           // some magic code here that grabs the $base64 variable from php
        })
        .error(function(){});
    }
    else{
        alert("Please upload an image");
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

$imgname = $_POST["FileName"];
$inputDir = "../../uploads/" . $imgname;
$outputDir = "../../processed/" . $imgname;

$MakeGray = "./makegray " . $inputDir . " " . $outputDir;
$runExec  = exec($MakeGray, $out);

$type = pathinfo($outputDir, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$data = file_get_contents($outputDir);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo "$base64";

?>
```

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive

Comment: I don't see how this is related? My question was related to the php backend.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot i could really use your help with this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter in success callback to fetch the response from server if available.

```
var base64 = ''; 
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url    : "../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.php",
    data   : MakeGray_Form,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).
    success(function(response){                     
          base64 = response; //response will contain whatever server echos to it's standard output
    })
    .error(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the response from server by using

```
.then(function (data) {}
```

and in "data" variable you can find the value you're looking for