# AngualrJS - Post request in empty

Tags: angularjs, post

I have this simple array and I need to make a post request to a backend controller but every time I get a empty array `[]`

Here my html:

```
<div class="input-container" ng-repeat="lang in languages">
    <label for="tagName">{{:: 'tagName' | translate }}</label>
    <input placeholder="{{:: 'tagName' | translate }}" id="tagName" type="text" ng-model="translations[lang]">
</div>
```

Here my JS:

```
$scope.createNewTag = function () {
    console.log($scope.translations);
    var data = $scope.translations;

    var method = 'post';
    var url = './tags';
    $http.post(url,data);      
};
```

The `console.log($scope.translations);` print: `[en:"hello", it:"ciao"]` but when I see in Chrome console the request playload is empty and in my controller I get an empty array.

What am I missing?

Comment: Explain downvote, otherwise are useless

Comment: have you tried just passing just $scope.translations instead of var data?

Comment: Yes, tried but still empty. If I hard code `data: { my_var: 'Hi'}` I get the result in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to resolve the promise of the post call, if you don't you won't  be able to handle the response.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data)
 .then(function(resp){
   //success
 }), function(err){
   //catch exception
 });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Regarding the empty payload i'd look through the code to check if there is any `http` interceptors that manipulate the request before it triggers, maybe you changed the `content-type` header there and Angular is not able to serialize the  data anymore.

maybe this could help you:

[Angularjs $http POST request empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213903/angularjs-http-post-request-empty-array)

**EDIT**: i see that you're passing an array as an argument, but `$http` specs states that it must be a key-value pair object, try wrapping your array inside an object.

```
var params = {
  data: $scope.translations
}
$http.post('/someUrl', params)
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that the data is not sent, I get an empty array in my php controller

Comment: really strange, angular serialize the parameters in the payload by itself, does the call reach the endpoint?

Comment: If I hard code data: { my_var: 'Hi'} I get the result in the controller

Comment: Still empty. The problem is in my data, I get `[en:"hello", it:"ciao"]` that is not a valid array, it should be: `[{en:"hello", it:"ciao"}]` but that is the data I get from the form and don't know how to change it